# Ubuntu 14.04 no longer detecting eth0

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I have set my `eth0` to **Shared Internet with other** and that used to work. 
I can't figure out what I may have done to break this, but the `eth0` doesn't seem to detect the link ... sometimes it does and get the expected **10.42.0.1** IP.

## My linux

```
~# uname -a 
Linux mymachine 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

## Boot

```
root@qb57:~# dmesg | grep eth0
[    1.827420] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 70:71:bc:82:41:f9
[    1.827422] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.827477] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 9, PHY: 9, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[   13.729334] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.152555] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.152818] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   17.938359] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   17.938475] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   17.939503] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  119.700357] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[  124.125948] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

Depending on the reboot, I may or may not get `eth0` ready

```
~# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no     <======================= NOT DETECTED ???
```

I tried bringing the link down and up again. Occasionally the link will come up with this operation ... but that's not consistent

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up

~# ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
~# ifup eth0  
Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0.
```

## /etc/network/interfaces

This may have been overwritten somehow. What's the original content of this file?

```
~# more /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#netmask 255.0.0.0
#gateway 10.0.0.1
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

#auto eth0:1
#iface eth0:1 inet static
#address 192.168.42.163
#netmask 255.0.0.0
#gateway 10.0.0.1
```

## Hardware

```
~# sudo lshw -C network
PCI (sysfs)  

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 70:71:bc:82:41:f9
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.12-5 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:41 memory:f0400000-f041ffff memory:f0424000-f0424fff ioport:1020(size=32)
```

## Any guidelines to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this link below: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2222204

Hope it will help, thanks